# Read iframe url after changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

used `iframe` to load a payment page in my html page. Then i used  `contentWindow.location.href` to read iframe page url when after it loaded. After payment process and transaction completed, url will changed. I want to read the url after transaction completed. Suffix of that returned url they mentioned `COMPLETED` or `CANCELED`. how to read that.

**my.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
    <iframe id="iframe_mercury" class="embed-responsive-item btn-block" src="mercurywindow.html" height="500px"></iframe>
 </div>
```

**script**

```
 var url = document.getElementById("iframe_mercury").contentWindow.location.href;
```

**mercurywindow.html**

```
 <body onload=document.frmCheckout.submit()>
    <form name=frmCheckout method=Post action="https://hc.mercurydev.net/mobile/mCheckout.aspx">
       <input name=PaymentID type=hidden value="28ff0296-d36d-476e-9a58-60e58241bb7b">
    </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$('#iframe_mercury').prop('src');
```

Or

```
$('#iframe_mercury').attr('src');
```

Comment: i want to read the iframe url after the payment completed. help me

Comment: How the url is getting changed?

Comment: i loaded the payment page within the iframe. Click submit on that page payment will completed and change the url like this https://hc.mercurydev.net/mobile/COMPLETED. i want to check the payment completed or not

Comment: If you have done the code for completing the payment and changing the url then it is already available to you i think.

Comment: sorry i don't have any code or something. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: No.. But if you know when the event is completing then hope you can find out the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can read the frame URL if it's pointing to a different domain.

Ref. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: In that returned url they mention transaction was completed or not. so i want to read that url after transaction

Comment: You can try adding the hash to the url. If you want to communicate with an iframe to the parent window.

Comment: Also check their documentation. I think the must have a provision to point to your own callback url. Once you are on your own domain you have the complete control with an iframe.